# How does $(1\ 2\ 3)$, an element of $S_4$ act on $\{1, 2\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3) \in S_4$ be a cycle. How does $(1\ 2\ 3)$ act on $\{1, 2\}$?

The definition of the action in Dummit & Foote "Abstract Algebra" says:

$$\sigma\cdot\{a_1,\cdots,a_k\} = \{\sigma(a_1),\cdots,\sigma(a_k)\}$$

Does this mean that the cycle acts like this?:

$$(1\ 2\ 3) \{1, 2\} = \{(1\ 2\ 3)(1), (1\ 2\ 3)(2)\} = \{3, 1\}$$

Which gets 3 from out of the set under the consideration (I mean we are applying the group action to $\{1, 2\}$, but have 3 in the return value from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$)?

Comment: Note that a group action is a more general concept: A group action is a map $* :G \times X \to X, (g,x) \mapsto g*x$ such that $e*x = x \forall x \in X$ and $g*(h*x)=(gh)*x \forall g,h \in G$ and $\forall x\in X$, where $G$ is the given group, $e$ is the neutral element of that group and $X$ is an *arbitrary*. 

So here you should specify first what $G$,$X$ and your group action $*$ is, otherwise it is impossible to answer this question.

If you want to learn more about it, I highly recommend *Algebra* by *M. Artin*. There is in fact a good translated version in German.

Comment: What is the order of the group $G$ generated by $(1\,2\,3)$?  What is the order of the group of permutations on $\{1,2\}$?  Can $G$ act on $\{1,2\}$ nontrivially?

Comment: Hmmm, you changed the problem statement.

Comment: @Batominovski sorry, as I was reading your  comments, I noticed that my question does not make sence. Thus I reformulated the question. Probably this was not the right way...

Comment: The initial question was full of mistakes. Then I edited the question, which still conists of several misunderstandings. But indeed it was good for me good to post this question, because I see that there have been problems. Seems that as @flawr mentioned that I should have given the definition of the group action, derived from the symmetric group. Then I should have applied the cycle $(1\ 2\ 3)(1) = 2$ and equally to 2. Thank you everyone who commented and answered on this post.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sigma \in S_n$ and $P$ be a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then define $\sigma(P) = \{\sigma(x) : x \in P\}$. So in your case you get $\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

A **group** $G$ acts (eventually) on a **set** $X$. That means roughly that every element of $g\in G$ is looked at as a bijection $g:X\to X$. See the comment of @flawr for further details.

The elements of $S_4$ are allready defined as bijections on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and we can speak of an action of group $S_4$ on set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Every action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ induces an action of group $G$ on $\wp(X)$. The bijection connected with $g\in G$ is the map $A\mapsto\{g.a\mid a\in A\}$.

In that context group $S_4$ acts on $\wp(\{1,2,3,4\})$ and element $(1\ 2\ 3)\in S_4$ sends set $\{1,2\}$ to set $\{2,3\}$.

However $S_4$ is **not acting** on set $\{1,2\}$.